# VM'ed Windows ME Works only in Safe Mode

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Using Ubuntu as a host machine, I tried emulating Windows ME (Millenium Edition) with VirtualBox 4.3. I started with the Boot Floppy, Used FDISK, Rebooted, Formatted C: & Started the Setup. It copies files and Installs Drivers, but upon the next  restart, the VM Freezes.
Then the VM was restarted, And when booting into Normal Mode, the same occurs. So, while booting into Safe Mode, it Works. Shutdown, Then started Again and same occours. Can anyone find a solution?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could just be windows ME being... as crappy as I remember it. Windows 98 SE is probably a better choice here.

Comment: ME was worse than Vista. XP is functionally-equivalent, and still gets Windows Updates (until April). Not worth trying to fix it IMHO.

Comment: I Knew That, It's Just that I have only a WinMe Disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would work when you run `fdisk`, use everything default. Then, Restart the Windows ME Guest with the DOS Floppy, and Go back into DOS. After it loads, type `format C:`. Then, type `E:\SETUP.EXE`. After the installation process finishes the 2nd stage (i.e. Hardware Search) it will restart. Mostly, it won't work. If it doesn't, Reboot with the DOS Floppy. Then, run `E:\SETUP.EXE`. It would ask whether to save Old Windows Files. Say 'No' and Continue. The process should be automated after that.